# How to pass custom ContractConverter to spring cloud contract docker image

Tags: spring-cloud, gradle-plugin, spring-cloud-contract

I want to use a custom ContractConverter to add custom fields to my contracts.
But the spring cloud contract plugin does not takes the CustomContractConverter class I have created to process the contracts.

I have created a demo project in github to demonstrate this:
https://github.com/javiersvg/custom-contracts

#### Code structure:

```
- src
  - test
    - resource
      - contracts
        - helath.yml                      -> A contract with a custom field.
      - META-INF
        - spring.factories                -> Custom contract converter configuration
    - groovy/com/.../
      - CustomContractConverter.groovy    -> Custom contract converter
```

#### How to run:

There is a docker-compose.yml file which copies the content of these folders into the `springcloud/spring-cloud-contract:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` docker image and runs the
`generateContractTests` task to create the tests based on the contracts.

#### Expected result:

An exception is thrown when the `CustomContractConverter` is called.

#### Actual result:

The process finishes with an exception due to the default YamlContracConverter class not being able to interprete the custom field in the contract.

#### What I have discovered so far:

Debugging the spring contract gradle plugin within the docker container (by adding the `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true` parameter to the docker-compose.yml command field) I see that the class `SpringFactoriesLoader(Line: 132)` which should load the spring.factories file is only loading files with that name from the jars defined as dependencies and not the one I added in the source code.
This is done through the `VisitableUrlClassLoader` which has the reference to the dependency jars and not the source code.
This is provably caused because the plugin does not load the source code until after it creates the contracts but this is only a theory.

Any experience with custom contract converters will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your own image with that file being on the classpath. Your groovy file needs to be compiled. We don't read scripts at runtime to retrieve additional converters

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It has been really helpful to understand.
I have made changes to the docker-compose.yml to:
- Add converter to ```src/main/``` folder
- Add ```compileGroovy``` task to compile converter

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
I have made changes to the docker-compose.yml to:
* Add converter to ```src/main/``` folder
* Add the spring.factories to the resources folder
* Add ```compileGroovy``` task to compile converter
- Copy build.gradle with groovy configurations

But the ContractFileScanner still does not take the converter

Comment: You don't understand. You need to create a new project that contains the meta inf and your setup. Create a jar from this and apply it to the gradles plugin classpath. Only then can you build a docker image

Comment: I understand now and I have tried it and it works. Thank you very much